# A product table contains 8000 records with 150 groups . How to fetch every 5 to 10th record from each and every group of products

Tags: sql, sas, proc

A product table contains 8000 records with 150 groups . How to fetch every 5 to 10th record from each and every group of  products in SAS as well as PROC SQL

Comment: How do you define the *ordering*, such that we can determine whether a particular record is the 5th or the 19th, etc?

Comment: `row_number over( PARTITION BY group_id ORDER BY product_nr) AS rn` in a subquery, and `WHERE rn >= 5 and rn < 10` in the outer query.

Comment: @joop this is not supported in SAS, this works only if you use an explicit pass-through to some database.

Comment: IIRC, SAS's PROC SQL supports window functions.

Comment: @joop unfortunately SAS Proc SQL doesn't support window functions, unless it's explicit pass through

Answer (score 1):

If i understand you correctly then something like this should solve the problem.

```
data YourData;
do group=1 to 150 ;
    do YourObs=1 to 54 ;
    output;
end;
end;
run; 

proc sort data=YourData Out=YourData_Sorted;
by Group;
run;

Data Final;
set YourData;
by Group;
if first.Group then Counter=0;
Counter+1;
if 5 <= Counter <= 10 ;
drop Counter;
run;
```